# Error while ant build on Developer sandbox : command 'ant pushdev'

Tags: contentversion, schema-builder

I am running in a build issue wile running the command 'ant pushdev'
Do I have to change the version number to latest? 
If yes which are the right places to change the version number?

Below is the error:
BUILD FAILED
/Users/xyz.nvbhjv/src/dev3/build.xml:37: FAILURES:
"Error: objects/Account.object(462,15):Property 'encodingKey' not valid in version 25.0
Error: objects/Case.object(379,15):Property 'encodingKey' not valid in version 25.0
Error: objects/Env_*c.object(536,15):Property 'encodingKey' not valid in version 25.0
Error: objects/Env*_c.object(556,15):Property 'encodingKey' not valid in version 25.0
Error: objects/St_*c.object(420,15):Property 'encodingKey' not valid in version 25.0
Error: objects/Stas*_c.object(433,15):Property 'encodingKey' not valid in version 25.0
Error: objects/Opportunity.object(349,15):Property 'encodingKey' not valid in version 25.0"

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you need to update the API version specified in your package.xml.

This can be a problem if for example someone gives you (or commits to source control) a file retrieved with a later version of the API. For example if I retrieve Account.object using v28 of the API and you try and deploy it using v25. In this case it includes properties (encodingKey) which are not recognised.

Try updating your package.xml used for deployment to the latest version number

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
       ... etc .. etc.. all the normal stuff here
    </types>
    <version>28.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Doug,Thank You for the response..try it out and update the post.

Comment: Documenting the behavior and work around: When I do refresh from server from the Force IDE on the files a lot of Object files get updated and the command line (using GIT: ant pushdev) build fails complaining. So the work around is to checkout all the conflicts (not the class and pages as they are intentionally modifies) eg: git checkout src/objects/. Now we run ant pushdev and the build is successful.